# What is the real world equivalent of a shadowcat?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *A Song of Ice and Fire*, there are references to shadowcats north of the Wall and in the Vale of Arryn. Are these supposed to be alternate names for a real feline, such as a puma or a lynx, or are they entirely fictional beasts?

Comment: Maybe Martin is a [Kitty Pryde](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Shadowcat) fan? Shadowcat being the only super-hero name she used for an extended period of time.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is a fictional animal and they are supposed to look like tigers or mountain lions, but with black fur.

[So Spake Martin](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Shadowcats_and_Clegane_Lands/):

> -Αre shadowcats closer in size to tigers or mountain lions?
>
> -Somewhere in between.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, the current photo looks more like a darkly-colored [lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx) to me.

Comment: Bred for its skills in magic, one assumes.

Answer (score 1):

I always thought that it is like a black panther?

[image: Black Panther]

Comment: Panther is a type of cat, there's no one animal called 'black panther'. I believe that's a picture of a jaguar, not sure though

Comment: @LeoKing Actually, the site it’s from claims it to be a panther: http://www.imagedirekt.com/en/royaltyfree-images-photos/1224861.html

Comment: @alexwlchan "a panther" is not a species of cat, it's a horribly-misused name for a bunch of different cats. Depending on where you live, a panther might be a cougar (not to be confused with a mountain lion), a jaguar, or a leopard. A quick google image search turns up this same photo named "puma", which implies that it's a black cougar, but up close all three look very similar.

Comment: More importantly, is there a reason why you (Stilgar) believe this to be the case?

Comment: Shadowcats are described having striped fur as well as it being black. So it doesn't really match all that well.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: And the Panthera genus includes lions and tigers, too.

Comment: @SystemDown many domestic black cats actually have black stripes of a slightly different black color that's only seen in some lighting situations. This can even be seen in great cats, though a bit harder to get close to for inspection.

Comment: @rodrigo that's true, but I don't think the term "panther" as a common name is used for lions and tigers; alternatively, "panther" is a common name for the cougar, which is not in *Panthera* but *Puma*.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield do cougars and leopards come in both black and spotted fur too? I thought panther was a black jaguar.

Comment: There are black (melanistic) leopards as well as jaguars, but the word "panther" does not always mean a jet-black cat. Where I live in Florida when people say "panther" they're usually talking about the "Florida panther" which is a species of cougar, and has the usual spotted coloring.

Comment: @Lou The "Black Panther" does exist in Malaysia and Indonesia. There are two different animals that goes by that name. Though to the locals it does not matter that they're different species since they're both black big cats. They are either leopard or jaguar with black spots on black fur. Though the Malay name for them in both Malaysia and Indonesia is Harimau Kumbang (trans. spotted tiger) the common English name for them in both speech and literature is Black Panther (English has been here since the early 1800s)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a type of large Lynx? The fur outstresching from the sides of the face, cheeks, and ears, are common amongst lynx broods.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you provide a source for this distinctive look?  What you describe is similar to a lynx; can you quote this description from one of the books or something JRRM has written?

Answer (score -2):

Hmm. Shadowcats?  I suspect a creature that appears much like a snow leopard. Long tail. Solitary in nature, generally, until it comes time to mate. Snow leopards are perhaps the most elusive of the large cats. They live high in the Andes mountains and rarely see one another, leave scent markings for one another - just as domestic, feral and any large cats. They have stripes and are nearly as large as tigers. George RR Martin could give the best answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you have any evidence that this was George R. R. Martin's intention? Because this answer sounds a lot like a guess, and we generally prefer answers posted here to be based on at least some evidence, rather than pure guesswork. You might want to take the [tour], to learn more aboiut the site.